# how to close this type of pop-ups using selenium java?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, popup

[in this page how to close the "Login/signup for Best Prices" popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlwXE.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The modal (not a pop-up) disappears when click on `<div class="makeFlex column flexOne whiteText latoBold">`. The simplest way is locate this webelement and click on it.

Another way is to remove the modal using javascript:

```
// need this import
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;

// declare webdriver
WebDriver driver = ...;

// declare javascript executor
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

// javascript to be executed, method getElementsByClassName(String classname) returns list of elements
String foo = "document.getElementsByClassName('autopop__wrap makeFlex column defaultCursor')[0].remove();"

// execute script
js.executeScript(foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one out

ChromeOptions options=new ChromeOptions();

Options.addArguments("--disable-infobars");

WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver(options);